# distributed scheduling system for R scripts

Tags: r, hadoop, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, scheduled-tasks

I would like to schedule and distribute on several machines - Windows or Ubuntu - (one task is only on one machine) the execution of R scripts (using RServe for instance).

I don't want to reinvent the wheel and would like to use a system that already exists to distribute these tasks in an optimal manner and ideally have a GUI to control the proper execution of the scripts.

1/ Is there a R package or a library that can be used for that?

2/ One library that seems to be quite widely used is mapReduce with Apache Hadoop.
I have no experience with this framework. What installation/plugin/setup would you advise for my purpose?

**Edit: Here are more details about my setup:**
I have indeed an office full of machines (small servers or workstations) that are sometimes also used for other purpose. I want to use the computing power of all these machines and distribute my R scripts on them.
I also need a scheduler eg. a tool to schedule the scripts at a fix time or regularly.
I am using both Windows and Ubuntu but a good solution on one of the system would be sufficient for now.
Finally, I don't need the server to get back the result of scripts. Scripts do stuff like accessing a database, saving files, etc, but do not return anything. I just would like to get back the errors/warnings if there are some.

Comment: Although I'm a fan of Hadoop, I would not recommend it for this context.  It's frustrating enough when the infrastructure is nearly homogenous, and one *only* needs to address package consistency.  It's quite another to have to address all kinds of issues on an ad hoc grid of different systems.  The only way I'd consider it for this scenario is to use a virtual machine, so that you can get an approximately homogeneous computing environment.  Virtualbox is one popular VM, if you do go that route.

Answer (score 2):

If what you are wanting to do is distribute jobs for parallel execution on machines you have physical access to, I *HIGHLY* recommend the doRedis backend for foreach. You can read the [vignette PDF](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRedis/vignettes/doRedis.pdf) to get more details. The gist is as follows:

> Why write a doRedis package? After all, the foreach package already
>   has available many parallel back end packages, including doMC, doSNOW
>   and doMPI. The doRedis package allows for dynamic pools of workers.
>   New workers may be added at any time, even in the middle of running
>   computations. This feature is relevant, for example, to modern cloud
>   computing environments. Users can make an economic decision to \turn
>   on" more computing resources at any time in order to accelerate
>   running computations. Similarly, modernThe doRedis Package cluster
>   resource allocation systems can dynamically schedule R workers as
>   cluster resources become available

Hadoop works best if the machines running Hadoop are dedicated to the cluster, and not borrowed. There's also considerable overhead to setting up Hadoop which can be worth the effort if you need the map/reduce algo and distributed storage provided by Hadoop.

So what, exactly is your configuration? Do you have an office full of machines you're wanting to distribute R jobs on? Do you have a dedicated cluster? Is this going to be EC2 or other "cloud" based?

The devil is in the details, so you can get better answers if the details are explicit.

If you want the workers to do jobs and have the results of the jobs reconfigured back in one master node, you'll be much better off using a dedicated R solution and not a system like TakTuk or dsh which are more general parallelization tools.

Comment: It's still a kludge.  Job distribution is a problem as old as parallel computing, and kids these days risk missing out on that by pretending that parallel computing started with Hadoop. But you are quite correct in noting that the OP severely underspecified his problem.

Comment: I think all of computing's a kludge. We just get comfortable with certain kludges after a while :)

Comment: You have been running a family of operating systems from the market leading vendor, haven't you?

Comment: Nope. But I have been using Excel a little today (God help me) so maybe that's where the sentiment comes from :)

Comment: @ Dirk Eddelbuettel: What would you suggest for this problem and that is not (or less) a kludge?

Comment: @ JD Long: I edited my question with more details. The tasks I want to distribute can also no be part of the same computation (not called by foreach). They are just independent tasks. Can this package use the pool of local and network workers for that purpose?

Comment: Cross-platform job scheduling is *hard*.  Keeping software and library versions linked is *hard*.  Research the problem a little; this is not a matter of just ordering a magic pony.

Comment: ok. Any thought specifically on Hadoop mapReduce ? I think I don't want to map and reduce, I just want to schedule independent scripts. Does that makes the problem simpler?

Comment: I don't think these are so hard.  If the worker is "atomic", i.e. all of the library components (in a general sense, aka "packages" in R), are discrete and the worker client is uniquely versioned, then one only needs to assure that these behave the same across platforms.  This is done in BOINC, for instance.  There's no reason that R on different operating systems should produce different outputs for standard computations.  I wouldn't do MapReduce, though - that's just asking for more pain if you're doing fairly simple stuff that could vary a lot between scripts.  Stick with doRedis.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [TakTuk](http://taktuk.gforge.inria.fr/) and [dsh](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html) as starting points. You could perhaps roll your own mechanism with [pssh](http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/) or [clusterssh](http://clusterssh.sourceforge.net/), though these may be more effort.